# How can I print several spreadsheets at specific times?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2003

I have an Excel workbook that has several worksheets in it.  Is there a  way one sheet automatically print at 8:00 am, another sheet automatically print at 10:00 am, another sheet automatically print at 12:00 noon and so on?

I am still using Office 2003

Answer (score 3):

First of all; **Welcome to Superuser**.

If you are familiar with Macros/VBA in excel, you can use the following code to get started. Sorry, this works for me, but I don't have Excel 2003 to test it before giving it to you. That means I can't guarantee it will work for you without some additional work.

Copy and paste this into a VBA module. You will need to change sheet names to be the names of your tabs.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Run "timer"
End Sub

Sub timer()
Application.OnTime TimeValue("08:00:00"), "Print_1"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("10:00:00"), "Print_2"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("12:00:00"), "Print_3"
End Sub

Sub Print_1()
' Prints the sheet for 8am
    Sheets("sheet1").Select
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1
End Sub

Sub Print_2()
' Prints the sheet for 10am
    Sheets("sheet2").Select
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1
End Sub

Sub Print_3()
' Prints the sheet for 12pm
    Sheets("sheet3").Select
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1
End Sub
```

Hope this helps you.

*Note: The system uses a 24 hour clock. So in order to use times after noon, add 12 to it. For instance, 3 pm is 15:00:00.*